# Is there a better way to write a right-recursive grammar's production rules than this?

Tags: recursion, compiler-construction, grammar

Scenario: Give production rules for a RIGHT-recursive grammar that
describes the set of all non-empty strings made from the characters
R and N, which may contain arbitrarily many contiguous
repetitions of R, but precisely two or precisely three contiguous
repetitions of N.

Answer:

A -> N B | R<sup>+</sup> A

B -> N D | N C | N ε

C -> N D | N ε

D -> R<sup>+</sup> D | R ε

Answer (score 1):

Incorrect:

```
A -> NNB | NNNB | RA | R
B -> R | RA | ε
```

edit: the above is not correct, I misunderstood the scenario.

Correct:

```
S -> RS | A
A -> NA | NB
B -> RB | RC
C -> NC | ND
D -> RD | RE | ε
E -> NE | NF
F -> RF | ε
```

How it works: 
It starts with S, that can generate 0 or more R or move to A, which generates the first group of Ns. Then it moves to B, which generates the Rs between 1st and 2nd group of Ns. Then it move to C, which generates the 2nd group of Ns. Then it moves to D, which can generate 0 or more Rs and either finish or move to E, which generates the 3rd group of Ns. Lastly it moves to F, which generates 0 or more Rs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this?

Comment: Are you sure this is correct, because it looks like you could have a sentence composed of just one R (A -> R), which wouldn't satisfy the 2-3 N's?

Comment: Oh. I probably misunderstood what you want. So I guess you want a grammar that will generate strings with exactly 2 or 3 groups of N's.

Answer (score 0):

This works just as well and is simpler:

```
S -> RS | A
A -> NA | NB
B -> RB | RC
C -> NC | ND
D -> RD | E
E -> NE | F
F -> RF | ε
```

It is the same up to D where instead of providing an ε option it provides an option to add another group of R's or go to E which is another group of N's, but this would not occur if there were no R's previously anyway as they would have been outputted as a conversion from C, and then another option to recursively add R's or an empty string.

Example  parse tree generated from the input NRNR

```
S
  \
   A
  / \
 N   B
    / \
   R   C
      / \
     N   D
        / \
       R   D
            \
             E
              \
               F
                \
                 ε
```